# Is it possible to pass class variables as parameters in the Symfony Controller?

Tags: php, facebook, symfony

I am trying to pass an object of FacebookSession class to my controller through generateUrl, but it gives me the following error

Warning: preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given in /Users/shashankm/Documents/Projects/myproject/app/cache/dev/classes.php line 888

```
if($session) {
            try {

                //Redirect to a link here with the session variable using generateUrl
                $url = $this->generateUrl('threadgab_userinfo_redirect', array('session' => $session), true);

                return $this->redirect($url);           

            } catch(FacebookRequestException $e) {

                //Create an error page for this scenario    
            }   
        }
```

The called controller is as follows:

I made the following code change as per Michaels answerbut it doesnt help:

```
/**
* @Route("/userinfo/{session}")
* @ParamConverter("session", class="Facebook:FacebookSession")
*/
class UserinfoController extends Controller 
{
    public function indexAction(FacebookSession $session)
    {
        return new Response("Got session id : ". $session->getToken());
    }
}
```

Is it possible to do this in Symfony?

Comment: For me the simpliest way to achieve you'r goal is to look at the dependency injection container, create a class, for the facebook session, deine it as a service, use it in you'r controller

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Do you really need to process requests with session-id or you just need to pass your session object to some controller?

Answer (score 0):

In order to pass an object into your Controller, you should pass it to the constructor of the Controller. This is done by declaring the Controller as a service, and 'injecting' the object into it. This is known as Dependency Injection; you are injecting an object that the Controller will depend upon.

To do this, we first need to restructure the constructor in the Controller, such that it now takes an object as an argument. In this example, I inject my own class, Boo, into my Controller, Foo

```
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Acme\DemoBundle\Classes\Bar;

class Foo extends Controller
{
    private $bar;

    public function __construct(Bar $bar){
        $this->bar = $bar
    }
}
```

We now need to declare this Controller as a Service:

```
// Acme/DemoBundle/Resources/config/services.yml
parameters:
    acme.controller.foo.class: Acme\DemoBundle\Controller\FooController
    acme.classes.bar.class: Acme\DemoBundle\Classes\Bar

services:
    acme.foo.controller:
        class: "%acme.controller.foo.class%"
        arguments: ['%acme.classes.bar.class%']
```

Here, we are saying that a `Foo` class is constructed by passing a `Bar` instance to it. `Foo` and `Bar` are recognised by their namespace in the `parameters` section.

Finally, we need to import the `services.yml` into the project:

```
// app/config/config.yml
imports:
    - { resource: "@AcmeDemoBundle/Resources/config/services.yml
```

Now each time you hit an Action within your Controller, your constructor would have been called, and your Bar object should be instantiated.